# Validate subquery count is not greater than x

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I am trying to create a function and a trigger that verify that the count of the `wid` and `rdate` columns inside the `responsibility` table is less than or equal to 10. I need to raise an exception when its greater than 10.

My subquery count is not working. When `COUNT()` is greater than 10, no exception is thrown.
What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_10() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN 
    IF (SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN wid = NEW.wid AND rdate = NEW.rdate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total FROM resposibility) > 10 THEN  
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'MAXIMUM OF 10 CAGE RESPONSIBILITES FOR EACH WORKER PER DATE';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

/* I've added update to make sure even when "updating" that row it will run the trigger check to verify */
CREATE TRIGGER insert_resp BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON resposibility
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_10();
```

Comment: @ConsiderMe: That's completely off target. A Postgres trigger function doesn't work like that.

Comment: I assume the typo in your sample code (`resposibility` without "n") has nothing to do with it? The trigger *would* seem ineffective, if you really created it for the wrong table!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are raising an `EXCEPTION` (and don't catch it), that will roll back the whole transaction immediately anyway. The `RETURN` statement simply doesn't matter in this case. Remove it.

It would be an *alternative* to use `RETURN NULL` *instead* of the exception if you want to silently skip the operation on only the current row and otherwise proceed normally.

The only obvious error in your code was `> 10` instead of **`>= 10`** [as pointed out by @a_horse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26854749/939860). And the typo in `resposibility`. The rest is a matter of efficiency.

Also, assignments are comparatively expensive in plpgsql, there is really no need here. Simplify:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_10()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$func$
BEGIN 
  IF (SELECT count(*) >= 10
      FROM   responsibility
      WHERE  wid = NEW.wid
      AND    rdate = NEW.rdate) THEN  

    RAISE EXCEPTION 'WORKER % ALREADY HAS MAX. OF 10 RESPONSIBILITES FOR DATE: %'
        , NEW.wid, NEW.rdate;
    -- no need for *any* RETURN statement here!
  END IF;

  RETURN NEW;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Be sure to have an **index** on `wid` and `rdate` or, ideally, a multicolumn index on `(wid, rdate)`.

Comment: When I tested my answer, I **had** to include the `return null` even after the `RAISE` to make this work.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Why did you have to? It's irrelevant what happens after the exception, it's never executed (unless you catch the error, which would be unusual for a trigger function).